# qprogressbar qfile

Tags: qt

I need to increment progressbar in qt everytime a file is copied from one location to another. Example there are 64 files to be copied. How is it possible to let the progressbar know the amount to increment by. Following is help code. Could you exhaust on it.

```
class MyClass : ...
{
...
public slots:
    void onWrite( qint64 );
};

MyClass::MyClass( ... )
{
    // ...
    progress->setMaximum( QFileInfo(fromFile).size() / 1024 );
    written = 0;
    connect( &toFile, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), SLOT(onWrite(qint64)) );
    // ...
}

void MyClass::onWrite( qint64 w )
{
    written += w;
    progress->setValue( written / 1024 );
}
```

Comment: Could you reformat your question so it is readable?

Comment: class MyClass : ...
{
...
public slots:
    void onWrite( qint64 );
};

MyClass::MyClass( ... )
{
    // ...
    progress->setMaximum( QFileInfo(fromFile).size() / 1024 );
    written = 0;
    connect( &toFile, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), SLOT(onWrite(qint64)) );
    // ...
}

void MyClass::onWrite( qint64 w )
{
    written += w;
    progress->setValue( written / 1024 );
}

Comment: Everytime a file is copied from one location to another, a progressbar should reflect it. Example say there are 64 files to be copied from local to server. How is it possible to let the progressbar know the amount to increment by. i found the above code on qtforum. I being a novice, fail to understand it in complete. Can u complete the picture for me. Thank you
subject :
RE: How to display the copy progress of QFile on QProgressBar

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the current value and add the new amount of bytes written to it.

```
void MyClass::onWrite(qint64 w)
{
    written += w;
    progress->setValue(progress->value() + written / 1024);
}
```

Comment: could u suggest a link that will explain this elaborately to me. this will help me digest the concept as well. thank you